# Can Visual Studio 2022 17.7 (With New Welcome Window) only display solutions?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

I'm glad to see the modal start window go away.  The new Welcome window introduced in 17.7 is a great improvement but does anyone know of a way to configure it to only show solution files and not project files?  I'm constantly removing projects and although it's only a minor pain I thought I'd put the question out there in case anyone is aware of a way to make it even better.

Comment: Send feedback to ask for this behavior!  Since it's a new feature, the product team is probably paying more attention to incoming feedback in this area.